# refresh some part after some time automatically without loading the page again in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have written code in PHP. Which shows posts done by different users. I have just included that page in another page just to view it along with other elements. Now i want that the portion which i have included must refresh after some interval automatically. I know it could be achieved by AJAX but I don't know much about it. below is the code on post.php file whic i have include in main page using `include"post.php";` now on the main page i want the the output of this code below refresh every 30seconds on main page but not reloading the page

```
<?php
$fetchpost=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from post where b_id IN (select u_id from frndlist where b_id='$b_id')");
?><?php
while($fpost=mysqli_fetch_array($fetchpost)){
    $author_id=$fpost[0];
    $post_id=$fpost[1];
    $post_date=$fpost[2];

    $inb_namefetch=mysqli_query($conn,"select b_name from ub_per where b_id='$author_id'");/*getting author's name*/
        $inb_mailfetch=mysqli_query($conn,"select b_email from ub_per where b_id='$author_id'");/*getting author's email*/
    $inb_mailfetched=mysqli_fetch_array($inb_mailfetch,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach($inb_mailfetched as $authormail){
        $authormail;
    }
    $inb_profpicfetch=mysqli_query($conn,"select prof_pic from ub_per where b_id='$author_id'");/*getting author's profile picture*/
    $inb_namefetched=mysqli_fetch_array($inb_namefetch,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $inb_profpicfetched=mysqli_fetch_array($inb_profpicfetch,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach($inb_profpicfetched as $fetchedimage){
        $piccheck=$fetchedimage;
    }
    if(isset($piccheck)){
    $authorimage="http://localhost/uploads/".$authormail."/profilepics/".$fetchedimage;

;   }else{$authorimage="http://localhost/content/user.jpg";}
    foreach($inb_namefetched as $authorl){
        $author=ucwords($authorl);
    }
    if(isset($fpost[3])){
    $post_content=$fpost[3];
}
    if(isset($fpost[4])){
    $post_image=$fpost[3];
}
?><div class="postingdiv">
<table>
<tr class="authortr" ><td class="author"><a id="imlink" href="http://localhost/profile/view_profile.php?id=<?php echo $author_id; ?>"><img class="authorpic" src="<?php echo $authorimage;?>"></a><a id="tlink" href="http://localhost/profile/view_profile.php?id=<?php echo $author_id; ?>"><?php echo $author; ?></a></td></tr>
<tr class="posttr" ><td class="post"><?php if(isset($post_content)){echo $post_content;} if(isset($post_image)){echo "<br><img id='postimg' src='http://localhost/uploads/".$author_mail."/postpics/".$postimage."'>";} ?></td></tr>

</table></div>
<?php include"commenter.php";
?>

<div class="makoment"><form name="mkoment" method="post" action="http://localhost/content/comment/makecomment.php" ><input type="hidden" name="commentere" value="<?php echo $b_id;  ?>"><input type="hidden" name="postsid" value="<?php echo $post_id;  ?>">  <textarea class="mycommentarea" name="accomment" placeholder="make a comment"></textarea><br><input type="submit" class="commentbutton" value="Comment"></form></div>
<br>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: We help you with what you're having issues with but if you don't have an issue and just *don't know much about it* you should do research first and at least try some things before posting here. It's quite simple but you have to be motivated enough to actually *want to understand without help first* then if that doesn't work or if your brain simply melts you come to us :)

Comment: can't post it here.its too large

Comment: Maybe just the part needed. You can edit your question to add your code.

Comment: ok understand the situation, idont think you need to see my code. firstly a base second a code file. code file included in base file using include"codefile.php". now i want to refresh codefile while base file should not refresh.in other  word whole page should not refresh

Comment: You need to understand that we need to be precis in our answer, so code snippet, desired output, problem specification needs to be good, if you just like some suggestions or comments SO is not the right place, google is...

Comment: okay i posted the code

Answer (score 0):

An example of doing so with *jQuery*:

```
setInterval(updateFn, 1000 /* or however long you want the interval */);

function updateFn(){
    $.post("page.php", function(response){
        console.log(response); //handle the data pinged back by the PHP page in the variable 'response'
    });
}
```

References:

- [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"path to php file",
        data:{key:value},//key value pairs
        type:"POST"
        success: function(data){
             alert(data);
        }
    });
},10000);
   ^ interval you want(now its 10 seconds)
```

Comment: the part i want to refresh is included in another page with include function. Now what will i be the url. the address of file which i have included or in which i have included

Comment: url will be your `.php` file from where you want to fetch the data.

Comment: okay but I still  have a doubt. That how should i use this code.just by describing script source only or any event should also be added like onclick or onkeyup etc

Comment: if you want to load onclick or on keypress, bind the event, else if you want to load on every 10 seconds, dont bind any event.

Comment: should i copy the code as it is or any changes need(except file path that i can understand)

Comment: data part... do you want to pass any data through ajax??

Comment: no all the queries are running on that page nothing

Comment: the code i posted will show the posts made by friends. i have written it on another file and included it on main file. now to see updates i have to refresh the window. now i want that i dont need to reload window just every 20 seconds the above code only automatically refreshes

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your current setup, so this is in general.

First, do a check on server side [if the request is made with AJAX](https://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax) so you can send a specific part of the page only or use a different route/page/file to serve the request.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    echo 'Requested with AJAX';
}
```

Then on the browser-side, use JavaScript to send a GET request every x seconds. Something like

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (ajax.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
    }

    ajax.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'); // Let PHP know we're doing it with AJAX.
    ajax.open("GET", "/posts.php", true);
    ajax.send();
}, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds.
```